# Making backup of MySQL database and server

Tags: mysql, backup

I know about database backups for MySQL, but how would one go about making a backup of entire MySql configuration along with the databases?

I'm building few set of services/tools and I need to provide instructions so not-so technical people could restore them if I wouldn't be available. One of the things I need to backup is self hosted MySql.

Can I just zip MySql folder and ProgramData MySql folder and would that make a complete restore solution? Just unzip and run service?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the simplest way is to use crontab+shell. Of course, there are also many paid software that can be implemented. If you want to back up, it is recommended that you back up your data files and configuration files so that they can be recovered. It is also the safest. The backup of mysql's installation files is of little significance, because it can be downloaded from official website at any time.